# Consult 2 class in Hibernate Search DSL

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate search DSL 4.4.0. And I met a problem recently.

E.g, I have 2 classes INDEXING and DATA_PROPERTY and I can't change them or creat a new class to associate 2 of them.

Now in the SQL, I use

```
SELECT IND.RDF_RESOURCE 
FROM INDEXING IND, DATA_PROPERTY DP
WHERE IND.RDF_RESOURCE = DP.RDF_RESOURCE
AND IND.OBJECT_TYPE_ID_INDEXED IN (........)
AND DP.PARTITION_VALUE IN (......)
AND .......
```

Part of Lucene indexing:

```
mapping.entity(DatatypeProperty.class).indexed().providedId()
       .property("rdfResource",ElementType.FIELD).field().analyze(Analyze.NO).store(Store.YES)
       .property("partitionValue", ElementType.FIELD).field().analyze(Analyze.NO)

mapping.entity(Indexing.class).indexed().providedId()
       .property("rdfResource",ElementType.FIELD).field().analyze(Analyze.NO).store(Store.YES)
```

There is no association between 2 of them.

How can I translate ***IND.RDF_RESOURCE = DP.RDF_RESOURCE*** in Hibernate Search DSL???

I have blocked here for a long time, thx for helping......

Comment: Here you are showing an SQL join, that's not something which relates to a Lucene index directly. You need to show your entities and how you index them. Are the entities mapping the INDEXING and DATA_PROPERTY tables associated? As the question stands now, there is not enough information to help you.

Comment: Sry for the absent information, I have edit the question.